# Disabling Alt+F4 function in key down event

Tags: vb.net

How to prevent form being closed by alt+f4 keys in keydown event? problem i am facing is keeping ALT key pressed and pressing F4 closes form but i want to prevent form from closing. Below is my code

```
Private Sub frminstituteselect_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Alt = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Private ALT_F4 As Boolean = False


Private Sub frminstituteselect_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Form1.FormClosing
    If ALT_F4 Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Return
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub frminstituteselect_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Form1.KeyDown
    ALT_F4 = (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.F4) AndAlso e.Alt = True)
End Sub
```

or simply

```
 Private Sub frminstituteselect_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Form1.FormClosing
            e.Cancel = True
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i don't want to use on form closing event. Let me explain you, i have a form and a button in it, on click of button the form should be closed but not on alt+f4 nor in form closing event. one more thing what i am trying to say is form will be closed by keeping ALT key pressed and pressing F4,this i don't want.

Comment: The code you mentioned will work if ALT and F4 keys are pressed separately.